# kivy set size on widget

Tags: widget, size, kivy

i created an Image object and i want to set size of it, but i cant do that.here is the code, i created an cursor object which is image, and then i try to set the size of it, but self.size = (10,10) has no effect on it. why it is not working?

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Cursor(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Cursor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'crosshair.png'
        self.size = (10,10)        
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self, input_type='text')
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self,**kwargs):
        print "hi"

    def _on_keyboard_down(self,keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'up': self.y += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'down': self.y -= 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'left': self.x -= 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'right': self.x += 10


class YardApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = Root()
        cursor = Cursor()
        layout.add_widget(cursor)
        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    YardApp().run()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its parent is a FloatLayout, which automatically sets the size and position of its children according to their pos_hint and size_hint. To disable this behaviour, set `self.size_hint = None, None`, after which your manual size setting will take effect.